# To run selenium through command prompt is there any third party files I need to add? If yes then how to add?

Tags: selenium, cmd

I want to run selenium test cases through CMD, is there any third party libraries I need to add, if yes please guide me

Answer (score 0):

This question is not very specific. Selenium is a library. If you're using Python or Java to implement selenium, you can run test cases through cmd like any other python/java program (`python program param1 param2 param3`). Make sure to get concrete targets to compare the results to, though, in order to ensure that your program is working properly when you're doing test cases. Hope that answered your question, but please leave any comments if you have any further questions.

Comment: To make it clear: let's take I have 50 test cases which are in java language, how to run these test cases using cmd?